# Python - correct order of the application of decorators

Tags: python, decorator

I'm decorating a function as such:

```
def some_abstract_decorator(func):
    @another_lower_level_decorator
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # ... details omitted
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This does what you'd expect (applies a low level decorator and then does some more stuff. My problem is that I now want to use `functools.wraps` and I don't know where to put it. This is my guess, but I don't know if it'll have unintended consequences.

```
def some_abstract_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    @another_lower_level_decorator
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # ... details omitted
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

(I of course apply `wraps` inside of `another_lower_level_decorator` as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it out:

```
from functools import wraps    

def another_lower_level_decorator(func):
    @wraps( func )
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

def some_abstract_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    @another_lower_level_decorator
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # ... details omitted
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@some_abstract_decorator
def test():
    """ This is a docstring that should be on the decorated function """
    pass

help(test)
```

Prints:

```
Help on function test in module __main__:

test(*args, **kwargs)
    This is a docstring that should be on the decorated function
```

As you can see it works! The docstring is there and the name assigned.

But this works just the same:

```
def some_abstract_decorator(func):
    @another_lower_level_decorator
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # ... details omitted
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

`wraps` just fixes the docstrings/names. As long as all the decorators use `wraps`, the order in which you apply it doesn't matter

Btw, there is [a much cooler decorator library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator):

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def another_decorator(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

@decorator
@another_decorator
def some_abstract_decorator(func, *args, **kwargs):
    # ... details omitted
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


@some_abstract_decorator
def test(x):
    """ this is a docstring that should be on the decorated function """
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. I think your first way it the correct way, after reading through this. I realized that if I use `@wraps(func)` after the inner decorator is applied, I'm assuming that the inner decorator also uses `wraps(func)`. By applying it to the decorated `wrapper` function I'm simply applying `wraps` functionality to my resulting function, thus making things more explicit (the low level decorator might be from a 3rd party, etc).

Answer (score 2):

That's right.  The way this works is

- `wrapper` is defined.  It calls `func` with its arguments.
- `another_lower_level_decorator` is called, with `wrapper` as its argument.  The function it returns becomes the new value of `wrapper`.
- `wraps(func)` is called to create a wrapper that will apply the name/docstring/etc. of `func` to whatever function it's called on.
- The return value of `wraps(func)`, i.e. the produced wrapper function, is passed the current value of `wrapper`.  This, remember, was the return value from `another_lower_level_decorator`.
- `wraps(func)(wrapper)` becomes the  new value of `wrapper`.
- That value is returned by `some_abstract_decorator`, making that function suitable for use as a decorator.

Or that's effectively it, anyway.  I think in practice `wrapper` is only reassigned to once.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks right to me.  `@another_lower_level_decorator` will return a function, which `@wraps` will wrap so that it has the same name as `func`.